# В anchorPane есть pane, его нужно заменить другим файлом .fxml

Tags: javafx, layout

Есть форма, где главным является *AnchorPane*, на нём расположены несколько *Pane*. Мне нужно при нажатии кнопки динамически менять один *Pane* на другой. Хочу сделать это по типу *Fragment* в *Android*. То есть написать несколько `.fxml` под каждую панель, и при нажатии определённой кнопки должно подгружать определённый *Pane* в *AnchorPane*. Хочу менять именно на `.fxml`. 
Есть ли такая возможность на *JavaFX* ?

Answer (score 3):

Проблема решена. `pane.getChildren().setAll((Node)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../layouts/pane.fxml")));`